# The type 'ClientBase<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, xamarin, .net-assembly

I'm having some troubles compiling this:

```
var client = new XMLSoccerCOM.DemoService.FootballDataDemoSoapClient();
```

client.CheckApiKey("my_api_key");

the CheckApiKey method is red and Xamarin says to me that "The type clientbase<> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Add a reference in the assembly to System.ServiceModel (...)"

What this error means?

Comment: Which part is unclear? That `FootballDataDemoSoapClient` requires `clientbase<>` which is defined in `System.ServiceModel` so you need to add a reference to it.

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to the assembly. In the Solution Explorer, under your project right-click References -> Add Reference. Find System.ServiceModel in the list of Framework Assemblies. Check the box for it and press OK.

Comment: Maybe isn't it compatible with portable libraries?